# How to calculate the required number of replicas per shard in ElasticSearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have to setup an ElasticSearch Cluster. For a high-availability scenario, is there any formula or method to compute the optimal or minimal required number of shards and replica per shard when the number of master-data nodes are provided ?

In my scenario, I have an ES cluster of 3 nodes, every node acts both as master and data node. I am using 6 primary shards.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/capacity-planning.html

Comment: https://qbox.io/blog/optimizing-elasticsearch-how-many-shards-per-index